# OneWay binding on WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a control with a property `public MyClass MyProperty{...}` which value is shown on the screen as a graph. I want this property to be bindable to any other `MyClass` in the program by using the `Binding` class (`MyProperty` would be the `propertyName` parameter in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wkkxwcz.aspx) `Binding` constructor, and the other `MyClass` would be the `dataMember` parameter) .

`MyClass` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so on that side everything is all right. But it happens that if I don't implement a `get` accessor in `MyProperty` and try to bind something to it, I get a *"Cannot bind to the property 'MyProperty' on the target control.
Parameter name: PropertyName"* error.

Does this mean I **have** to implement a `get` accessor even if I know I will never need to read it's value and I want a OneWay (source to target) binding, and even if I just return `null` in the `get` accessor?

I'm guessing the `Binding` class uses this to compare the new value to the old one or to do some other internal stuff. I'm not sure, then, if it's a good idea to just return `null`, or it would be better to keep always a copy of whatever last object was assigned with the `set` accessor and return it in the `get` accessor. Maybe I really don't even need to write a `get` accessor and I'm doing something else wrong. It just happens that I get the error only when I comment out the `get` accessor and stop getting it when I put it back.

**Edit:** In case there is any confusion: When I say `MyProperty`'s value is shown on the screen as a graph I don't mean it has a value that some other code reads and show in the screen. No one reads any value from `MyProperty`. `MyProperty`'s `set` accessor is the one that draws stuff on the screen and that's the end of the cycle.

Comment: Please reformat this to use paragraphs.

Comment: There's a OneWayToSource binding, too.  It's hard to tell if it will solve your problem, because I can't read through the whole thing :)  Give some short clips of example code, too.

Comment: Actually I thought about paragraphs but wasn't sure where to put them. I'll just put them somewhere around :).

Comment: By the way how do you need you need code samples if you didn't read the whole thing? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but I think the exception you're encountering stems from the `Binding` class's `CheckBinding` function (reflectored):

```
if (descriptor.IsReadOnly && (this.controlUpdateMode != ControlUpdateMode.Never))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("ListBindingBindPropertyReadOnly", new object[] { this.propertyName }), "PropertyName");
}
```

Therefore, changing the Binding's `ControlUpdateMode` to `ControlUpdateMode.Never` may be what you're looking for